# Pecl OAuth Post Image

Tags: php, image, oauth, pecl

I have a problem in posting image to server (specific URL) through pecl oauth. I have been googling it, but not yet get the answer.

I'm using this codes :

```
function postData($url, $token,$data=null){
        $oauth = new OAuth(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY,OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        $oauth->disableSSLChecks();
        $oauth->setToken($token->key,$token->secret);
        $oauth->fetch($url,$data, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);
        return $oauth->getLastResponse();
    }

function questionPost(){
        $user_auth = $this->session->userdata('login_user');
        $content =  $this->input->post('content');
        $aExtraInfo = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);   
        $sImage = "data:" . $aExtraInfo["mime"] . ";base64," . base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $data = array(
            "content"=>$content,
            "attachment"=>$sImage
        );
        $url = "https://externalURL";
        $this->function_model->postData($url, $user_auth->accessToken, $data);
        echo json_encode(array("status"=>"success","message"=>"success"));
    }
```

i got error 500 after running questionPost();

Really appreciate any kind of answer.